# Maven proxy - Not authorized by proxy

Tags: maven

How do I set up proxy for maven in eclipse?

```
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: 
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
Not authorized by proxy , ReasonPhrase:authenticationrequired. 
-> [Help 1] 
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: 
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
```

Comment: Did you add option `proxyUsername` & `proxyPassword` ?

Comment: yup, I forgot it.
I have to click on update button to apply the change.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the proxy to the `settings.xml`:

https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: yup, I have resolved this problem.